# How to prevent non-specialized template instantiation?

Tags: c++, templates, boost, compilation

I have a templated `class` (call it `Foo`) which has several specializations. I would like the compilation to fail if someone tries to use an unspecialized version of `Foo`.

Here is what I actually have:

```
template <typename Type>
class Foo
{
  Foo() { cannot_instantiate_an_unspecialized_Foo(); }

  // This method is NEVER defined to prevent linking.
  // Its name was chosen to provide a clear explanation why the compilation failed.
  void cannot_instantiate_an_unspecialized_Foo();
};

template <>
class Foo<int>
{    };

template <>
class Foo<double>
{    };
```

So that:

```
int main()
{
  Foo<int> foo;
}
```

Works while:

```
int main()
{
  Foo<char> foo;
}
```

Does not.

Obviously, the compiler chain only complains when the linking process takes place. But is there a way to make it complain before ?

I can use `boost`.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Just don't define the class:

```
template <typename Type>
class Foo;

template <>
class Foo<int> { };

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    Foo<int> f; // Fine, Foo<int> exists
    Foo<char> fc; // Error, incomplete type
    return 0;
}
```

Why does this work? Simply because there *isn't* any generic template. Declared, yes, but not defined.

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess I was looking for something too complicated.

Comment: @Schnommus But if you do define the class and it has a static_assert, shouldn't it never be instantiated because the specialization matches better?

Comment: It is bad decision, because error will be issued on linking stage, not on compiling. And you will never know where exactly you used non-specialized class.

Comment: On one hand this is a simple solution but a downside is the less readable error message than what you'd have with `static_assert` as in @Luc Danton's answer.

Answer (score 26):

You can simply *not define* the base case:

```
template <typename> class Foo;             // no definition!

template <> class Foo<int> { /* ... */ };  // Foo<int> is OK
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that... Thank you. Accepted Schnommus answer's because he has lower reputation. Upvoted this one for fairness.

Answer (score 21):

A trick for C++0x (also available with a C++03 `static_assert` emulation, but the error message isn't necessarily better than leaving the primary template undefined):

```
template<typename T>
struct dependent_false: std::false_type {};

template<typename Type>
struct Foo {
    static_assert( dependent_false<Type>::value
                 , "Only specializations of Foo may be used" );
};
```

The assertion will only trigger when `Foo` is instantiated with the primary template. Using `static_assert( false, ... )` would trigger the assertion all the time.

Comment: A similar trick that needs less to type is to use static_assert(sizeof(Type) == 0, "..."); As an alternative you can use BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT. I personally prefer those, as the above "don't define the base template" can lead to linker errors when you just work with references/pointers. Also often you should stop for a moment and rethink if you really need this, as templates are meant to be generic, which you are restricting here

Comment: How does this work? Wouldn't you need to define `dependent_false<Specialization> : std::true_type {}` for every `Specialization`, or else `dependent_false<Type>::value` would always be false?

Comment: @mako It is meant to be always false. If you have e.g. a `Foo<int>` explicit specialization defined somewhere, then it shouldn’t contain this particular assertion. So when *that* specialization is instantiated, no assertion is triggered—the primary template has no bearing on an explicit or partial specialiation.

Comment: And using a template with a parameter instead of just `false` is just done to prevent static_assert from going off until someone instantiates the unspecialized template class, right?

Comment: @mako That’s right. `static_assert( false );` would always trigger. If you’re interested in looking deeper into this you might want to look for dependent types and expressions (from which `dependent_false` takes its name of course).