# Is it possible to prevent a C++ template being used without specialization?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

Is it possible to prevent a C++ template being used without specialization?

For example, I have

```
template<class T>
void foo() {}
```

And I don't want it to be used without being specialized for `foo<int>` or `foo<char>`.

Comment: Uh, just don't use a template?

Comment: @DarenW: You can have specialized templates that are still generic, e.g. `template<typename T> void foo<T*>()` is specialized for any pointer type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent non-specialized template instantiation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064039/how-to-prevent-non-specialized-template-instantiation)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to declare the function without actually defining it in the generic case. This will cause a reference to an unspecialized template to emit an Undefined Symbol linker error.

```
template<class T>
void foo();

template<>
void foo<int>() {
    // do something here
}
```

This works just fine for me with `clang++`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  undefined type in body of function. And you will get **compile time** error message:

```
template<class T> struct A;  
template<class T>  
void foo()  
{  
   typename A<T>::type a;  // template being used without specialization!!!
   cout << "foo()\n";  
}  
template<>  
void foo<int>()  
{  
   cout << "foo<int>\n";  
}  
template<>  
void foo<char>()  
{  
   cout << "foo<char>\n";  
}  
int main()  
{  
  foo<int>();  
  foo<char>();  
//  foo<double>();   //uncomment and see compilation error!!!
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's possible when foo function have parameter.
for example: template void foo(T param){}
now, u can call foo(1), foo('c') without specializing.