# Disable template but allow specializations

Tags: c++, templates

For example, I have declared a generic template:

```
template <class T>
void foo(T value);
```

But I need that a programmer for every type must declare its specialization:

```
struct my_user_t
{
// ...
};

template <>
void foo<my_user_t>(my_user_t value) {
  // ...
}

// Somewhere in big program:
my_user_t my_value;
foo(my_value);
```

And for now if the programmer forgot to specialize the template for his user type, linker says that it cannot find symbol, not compiler. So in big program it is hard to find where it was used.

How can I declare the template like:

```
template <class T>
void foo(T value) {
    static_assert(???, "You must specialize foo<> for your type");
}
```

such that the compiler (not linker) will say where I used `foo(my_user_t)` incorrectly?

Comment: Which C++ standard are you using?

Comment: Here's a better dup. I asked almost the exact same thing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39250545/sfinae-to-make-base-template-always-result-in-error

Answer (score 6):

Just make up something that is dependent on the template parameter type:

```
template<typename T>
struct always_false : std::false_type {};

template <class T>
void foo(T value) {
    static_assert(always_false<T>::value , "You must specialize foo<> for your type");
}
```

---

Alternatively, I think you can declare the default function template as deleted:

```
template <class T>
void foo(T value)=delete;
```

Comment: This is still ill-formed NDR to a sufficiently clever compiler :)

Comment: I see. Would a custom `totally_always_false<T>` trait work, since the compiler can't be sure that I haven't specialized it somewhere?

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much the canonical way of doing this.

Comment: [Correct, that's a common trick](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7064165/1938163)

Comment: Yes, it works, but both variants disable the common template for convertible types. For example, you have specialization for `foo<std::string>()`, and without that trick you can actually call it with `const char *`. But with this trick it is automatically disabled. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: @vladon not easily. If you want to have function overloading experience, use function overloading.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an offering using `sizeof`:

```
template<class T> void foo(T) {
    static_assert(sizeof(T) != sizeof(T), "You must specialize foo<> for your type");
}
```

Comment: Does `static_assert(false, "You must specialize foo<> for your type");` make any difference?

Comment: Yup.  It makes a big difference. See for yourself. You

Comment: Just checked, `sizeof(T) != sizeof(T)` does compile. So it can compile but there is no type that satisfies this template, thus actually making it impossible to use. Very clever. `std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, T>::value>::type` would be more explanatory to me though

Answer (score 0):

You could use function overloads instead of templates.
So the compiler will have to see its declaration at least, while a programmer most probably will not forget to add a function definition once they added a declaration for thier own type.

Another approach is to use class templates with an empty class definition (the function will become a member function).